# Here SDK lite for iOS contains unsupported files

Tags: ios, sdk, here-api, xcframework, heremaps-ios-sdk

We recently integrated the Here SDK lite for iOS in our app and during the submission to the AppStore, we discover that the xcframework contains unsupported files.

> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font at
> 'Subito.app/Frameworks/heresdk.framework/style/fonts/FiraGO-Map.woff'.
> Font not supported by platform.
>
> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font at
> 'Subito.app/Frameworks/heresdk.framework/style/fonts/DroidSansFallback.woff'.
> Font not supported by platform.
>
> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font at
> 'Subito.app/Frameworks/heresdk.framework/style/fonts/FiraGO-Italic.woff'.
> Font not supported by platform.

We didn't find any instructions on the official documentation about stripping these files before submitting to the store, but that's what we proceeded to do, since we are not using any UI related component coming from the SDK at the moment. I hope that it's a safe operation (resulting app seems to work fine).

Are there any other folders that could/should be removed from the xcframework before the submission to the store (e.g. style folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HERE SDK contains several fonts to render map labels in different languages. If you want to strip those files - or if you want to optimize the size of the overall app, you can remove selected fonts. For example, the font with Chinese, Japanese and Korean characters is around 1.7MB. To remove this font, open the heresdk.framework file and remove the following files:

- style/fonts/DroidSansFallback.woff
- style/fonts/DroidSansFallback.license

When you remove the font, it is recommended to switch the map language to any other language than Chinese, Japanese or Korean.

Check also the map / language [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-lite/4.8.3.0/dev_guide/topics/key-concepts.html#maps) with more related info.

This should help at least as a workaround until the faulty fonts are fixed by the HERE SDK team with a newer HERE SDK release.

For your question: You can also remove the related license file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's seemed strange that the SDK contains such kind of files and no one raised the issue before (at least I didn't find anything here on stackoverflow). This made me doubt about the adoption of the SDK on the real world, is something that's really used and already tested?

Comment: The HERE team releases every two weeks, so I do not know when this issue was introduced. But usually, HERE is very fast with fixing regressions.

Comment: PS: I use the Explore Edition for iOS instead of Lite, and there are no related issues. It works just fine bringing it to the App Store. I assume Lite iOS is targeting only very special use cases.

Comment: Update: The files mentioned in the question are no longer included in the latest HERE SDK release 4.9.1, however, the answer is still valid as it explains in general how to remove files from the framework.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My actual point was how those kind of files might be available in the framework in the first place, since they are not allowed and results in a rejected App submission.